# How can I access Google Sheets spreadsheets only with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I want to access Google Spreadsheets using JavaScript only (no .NET, C#, Java, etc.)

I came [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples.html) and was shocked to know that there is NO API for JavaScript to access Google Sheets.

Please tell me how to access (CREATE/EDIT/DELETE) Google Sheets using JavaScript or any of its frameworks like jQuery.

Comment: the link you provided has information about using JSON. you should be able to use that in JavaScript.

Comment: @GSto it would be helpful if u can provide me some insight to this.let me tel u again i want to access google spreadsheet via javascript.Thanks.

Comment: This is the full tutorial https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

Comment: Might want to consider using Sheetsu. It's fairly simple for JSON API and limited with the free version, but it really simplifies what any dev should need for using Google spreadsheets. Hope this helps some people.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I have created a simple javascript library that retrieves google spreadsheet data (if they are published) via the JSON api:

https://github.com/mikeymckay/google-spreadsheet-javascript

You can see it in action here:

http://mikeymckay.github.com/google-spreadsheet-javascript/sample.html

Comment: This saved me a ton of time. Thank you so much!
  

I did, however, decide to fork your code, to be able to handle empty cells of data, and also organize it into rows (the data being returned as is is just a giant array of cells, but since empty cells weren't being taken into account, there was no easy way to organize the data).
  

The update was just to your 'callbackCells()' method. Check it out:
https://github.com/rw3iss/google-spreadsheet-javascript.git
  

Thanks again man!

Comment: Evan Plaice's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8666573/42082 has more detailed information about the official Google Docs API and how to use the spreadsheet one. Worth a look.

Comment: new version API 3.0 and Oauth 2.0

Comment: Looks like google changed policy and this is broken now.

Answer (score 66):

**Jan 2018 UPDATE**: When I answered this question last year, I neglected to mention a *third* way to access Google APIs with JavaScript, and that would be from Node.js apps using *its* client library, so I added it below.

It's ***Mar 2017***, and most of the answers here are outdated -- the accepted answer now refers to a library that uses an older API version. A more current answer: you can access [most Google APIs](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis) with JavaScript only. Google provides 2 (correction, 3) ways to do this today:

1. As mentioned in the [answer by Dan Dascalescu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323377/305689), you can use **[Google Apps Script](http://developers.google.com/apps-script)**, the JavaScript-in-Google's-cloud solution. That is, non-Node server-side JS apps outside the browser that run on Google servers.

- You code your apps in the [Apps Script code editor](http://script.google.com), and they can access Google Sheets in two different ways:

  - The [Spreadsheet Service](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) (native object support; [usage guide](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)); native is easier but is generally older than...
  - The [Google Sheets Advanced Service](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) (directly access the latest Google Sheets REST API [see below]; [usage guide](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced))
- Apps Script also powers [add-ons](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/), and you can extend Sheets UI functionality with Sheets add-ons (like [these](http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create?addon_store))
- You can even write [mobile add-ons](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/mobile/) which extend the [Sheets app on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets)
- To learn more about using Apps Script, check out [these videos](https://web.archive.org/web/20220929161227/https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/videos) I've created (most involve the use of Sheets)

2. You can also use the **[Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript)** to access the latest [Google Sheets REST API](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api) on the client side.

- Here are [some generic samples](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples) of using the client library
- The latest Sheets API (v4) was [released](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2016/05/apps-dev-sheets-api.html) at Google I/O 2016; it's much more powerful than all previous versions, giving developers programmatic access to most features found in the Sheets UI
- Here is the [JavaScript quickstart](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) for the API to help you get started
- Here are [sample "recipes"](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/) (JSON payloads) for core API requests
- If you're not "allergic" to Python (if you are, just pretend it's pseudocode ;) ), I made several videos with more "real-world" samples of using the API you can learn from and migrate to JS if desired (NOTE: even though it's Python code, most API requests have JSON & easily portable to JS):

  1. [Migrating SQL data to a Sheet](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2016/06/introducing-google-sheets-api-v4.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/06/using-new-google-sheets-api.html))
  2. [Formatting text using the Sheets API](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/formatting-cells-with-the-google-sheets-api.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/09/formatting-cells-in-google-sheets-with.html))
  3. [Generating slides from spreadsheet data](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/generating-slides-from-spreadsheet-data.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/11/generating-slides-from-spreadsheet-data.html))
  4. Those and others in the [Sheets API video library](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/videos)

3. The 3rd way to access Google APIs with JavaScript is from the **[Node.js client library](http://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client)** on the server-side. It works similarly to using the JavaScript (client) client library described just above, only you'll be accessing the same API from the server-side. Here's [the Node.js Quickstart example](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) for Sheets. You may find the Python-based videos above to be even more useful as they too access the API from the server-side.

When using the REST API, you need to manage & store your source code as well as perform authorization by rolling your own auth code (see samples above). Apps Script handles this on your behalf, managing the data (reducing the "pain" as mentioned by Ape-inago in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4332445/305689)), and your code is stored on Google's servers. But your functionality is restricted to what services App Script provides whereas the REST API gives developers much broader access to the API. But hey, it's good to have choices, right? In summary, to answer the OP original question, instead of zero, developers have **three** ways of accessing Google Sheets using JavaScript.

Answer (score 37):

**Here's the Gist.**

You can create a spreadsheet using the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/). There is currently no way to delete a spreadsheet using the API (read the documentation). Think of Google Docs API as the route to create and look-up documents.

You can add/remove worksheets within the spreadsheet using the [worksheet based feeds](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#WorksheetFeeds).

Updating a spreadsheet is done through either [list based feeds](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#ListFeeds) or [cell based feeds](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#CellFeeds).

Reading the spreadsheet can be done through either the Google Spreadsheets APIs mentioned above or, *for published sheets only*, by using the [Google Visualization API Query Language](http://blog.ouseful.info/2009/05/18/using-google-spreadsheets-as-a-databace-with-the-google-visualisation-api-query-language/) to query the data (which can return results in CSV, JSON, or HTML table format).

---

Forget jQuery. jQuery is only really valuable if you're traversing the DOM. Since GAS (Google Apps Scripting) doesn't use the DOM jQuery will add no value to your code. Stick to vanilla.

I'm really surprised that nobody has provided this information in an answer yet. Not only **can** it be done, but it's relatively easy to do using vanilla JS. The only exception being the Google Visualization API which is relatively new (as of 2011). The Visualization API also works exclusively through a HTTP query string URI.

Answer (score 20):

There's a solution that does not require one to publish the spreadsheet. However, the sheet does need to be 'Shared'. More specifically, one needs to share the sheet in a manner where anyone with the link can access the spreadsheet. Once this is done, one can use the Google Sheets HTTP API.

First up, you need an Google API key. Head here:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key
NB. Please be aware of the security ramifications of having an API key made available to the public: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037

### Get *all* data for a spreadsheet -  warning, this can be a lot of data.

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/?key={yourAPIKey}&includeGridData=true
```

### Get sheet metadata

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/?key={yourAPIKey}
```

### Get a range of cells

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{sheetName}!{cellRange}?key={yourAPIKey}
```

Now armed with this information, one can use AJAX to retrieve data and then manipulate it in JavaScript. I would recommend using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

```
var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/?key={yourAPIKey}&includeGridData=true";                                                             
axios.get(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);                                                                                                                                                    
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);                                                                                                                                                       
  });
```

Comment: What is grid data?

Comment: @WilliamEntriken The contents of the cells.

Answer (score 13):

**2016 update**: The easiest way is to use the Google Apps Script API, in particular the [SpreadSheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). This works for private sheets, unlike the other answers that require the spreadsheet to be published.

This will let you bind JavaScript code to a Google Sheet, and execute it when the sheet is opened, or when a menu item (that you can define) is selected.

Here's a [Quickstart/Demo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros). The code looks like this:

```js
// Let's say you have a sheet of First, Last, email and you want to return the email of the
// row the user has placed the cursor on.
function getActiveEmail() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRow = activeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var email = activeSheet.getRange(activeRow, 3).getValue();

  return email;
}
```

You can also [publish such scripts as web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Answer (score 6):

> ***edit:*** This was answered before the google doc's api was released. See [Evan Plaice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8666573/42082) and [Dan Dascalescu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323377/42082) for more up-to-date
>   information.

It looks lke you can, but it's a pain to use.  It involves using the Google data API.

http://gdatatips.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-javascript-client-library-w-non.html

"The JavaScript client library has helper methods for Calendar, Contacts, Blogger, and Google Finance. However, you can use it with just about any Google Data API to access authenticated/private feeds. This example uses the DocList API."

and an example of writing a gadget that interfaces with spreadsheets: http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/gadgets/

Comment: why u call it as "pain".whats harm in doing so ?

Comment: A pain because it doesn't have a native api, which means you need to do a lot of parsing and data manipulation yourself.  a native spreadsheet api would provide these for you.

Answer (score 4):

'JavaScript accessing Google Docs' would be tedious to implement and moreover Google documentation is also not that simple to get it.  I have some good links to share by which you can achieve js access to gdoc:

> http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs
>
> http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/gadgets/
>
> http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/js.html
>
> http://www.mail-archive.com/google-help-dataapi@googlegroups.com/msg01924.html

May be these would help you out..

Comment: [link 1](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs) will be deprecated On April 20, 2015, [link 2](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/gadgets/) 404 error, [link 3](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/js?csw=1) v2.0 deprecated, [link 4](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-help-dataapi@googlegroups.com/msg01924.html) deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this is a lousy answer.  Apparently this has been an [issue](http://groups.google.com/group/google-help-dataapi/browse_thread/thread/eceba34c7fbc58e3) for almost two years so don't hold your breath.

Here is the official request that you can ["star"](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=7&q=spreadsheet)

Probably the closest you can come is [rolling your own service with Google App Engine/Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/more_google_data.html) and exposing whatever subset you need with your own JS library.  Though I'd love to have a better solution myself.

Answer (score 2):

In this fast changing world most of these link are obsolet.

Now you can use [**Google Drive Web APIs**](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/):

- [Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java)
- [PHP](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/php)
- [Javacript](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/js)
- [.NET](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/cs)
- [Python](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python)
- [Ruby](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/ruby)
- and others...

Comment: The OP asked about [Google Sheets specifically, which has a more specific API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) than Drive.

Comment: ok, here is [the full list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/products) of Google products including spreadsheet (easy to find using my first link though)

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by using [Sheetsee.js](http://jlord.us/sheetsee.js/) and tabletop.js

1. [example from git](https://github.com/amowu/angular-spreadsheet-sample)
2. [another Example](http://www.mikeball.us/blog/using-google-spreadsheets-and-tabletop-as-a-back-end/)

Answer (score 1):

You can read Google Sheets spreadsheets data in JavaScript by using the RGraph sheets connector:

https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/docs/import-data-from-google-sheets.html

Initially (a few years ago) this relied on some RGraph functions to work its magic - but now it can work **standalone** (ie not requiring the RGraph common library).

Some example code (this example makes an RGraph chart):

```
<!-- Include the sheets library -->
<script src="RGraph.common.sheets.js"></script>

<!-- Include these two RGraph libraries to make the chart -->
<script src="RGraph.common.key.js"></script>
<script src="RGraph.bar.js"></script>

<script>
    // Create a new RGraph Sheets object using the spreadsheet's key and
    // the callback function that creates the chart. The RGraph.Sheets object is
    // passed to the callback function as an argument so it doesn't need to be
    // assigned to a variable when it's created
    new RGraph.Sheets('1ncvARBgXaDjzuca9i7Jyep6JTv9kms-bbIzyAxbaT0E', function (sheet)
    {
        // Get the labels from the spreadsheet by retrieving part of the first row
        var labels = sheet.get('A2:A7');

        // Use the column headers (ie the names) as the key
        var key = sheet.get('B1:E1');

        // Get the data from the sheet as the data for the chart
        var data   = [
            sheet.get('B2:E2'), // January
            sheet.get('B3:E3'), // February
            sheet.get('B4:E4'), // March
            sheet.get('B5:E5'), // April
            sheet.get('B6:E6'), // May
            sheet.get('B7:E7')  // June
        ];

        // Create and configure the chart; using the information retrieved above
        // from the spreadsheet
        var bar = new RGraph.Bar({
            id: 'cvs',
            data: data,
            options: {
                backgroundGridVlines: false,
                backgroundGridBorder: false,
                xaxisLabels: labels,
                xaxisLabelsOffsety: 5,
                colors: ['#A8E6CF','#DCEDC1','#FFD3B6','#FFAAA5'],
                shadow: false,
                colorsStroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                yaxis: false,
                marginLeft: 40,
                marginBottom: 35,
                marginRight: 40,
                key: key,
                keyBoxed: false,
                keyPosition: 'margin',
                keyTextSize: 12,
                textSize: 12,
                textAccessible: false,
                axesColor: '#aaa'
            }
        }).wave();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: And now there's a PHP version of the import utility - available at the same URL

Answer (score -1):

For this type of thing you should use [Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/drive/apps.html#fusiontables). The [API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) is designed for that purpose.

Comment: Not a good idea. Google is going to shut it down. Downvoting it.