# Javascript access google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can javascript retrieve username and password from google spreadsheet, where google spreadsheet store username and password like below,

> row 1  user1,pass1
>   row 2  user2,pass2

Comment: Javascript running where?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143901/access-google-spreadsheet-or-google-data-api-only-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You directly can not use JavaScript to access Google Spreadsheet. Instead you can use Google Apps Script having almost all functionalities of JavaScript. You can read about Google Apps Script [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/?hl=en)

Using Apps Script [Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/?hl=en) you can perform CRUD operations on spreadsheet. Hope this helps

Comment: That's not accurate. You can file/publish the spreadsheet and access it as JSONP without any API. It wouldn't be a good thing to do when there are passwords stored there, but it's not impossible.