# Google Script WebApp html Search from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: search, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had a web app with a form that sends data to a Google Spreadsheet. 
Now I want to create another html page with a search function to pull data from the Google sheet and display it on my html page.
Is there a way to do that? PLEASE HELP.
I have looked everywhere but no codes were helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143901/how-can-i-access-google-sheet-spreadsheets-only-with-javascript - there's a perfect answer from @Mike McKay

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please read this [Why can someone help me is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A  search dialog and webapp**

Code.gs:

```
function findNeedleInHaystack(sObj) {
  var sObj=sObj||{};
  sObj.column=sObj.column||1;
  sObj.needle=sObj.needle||22;
  sObj.haystack=sObj.haystack||'Sheet1';
  sObj.startrow=sObj.startrow||2;
  sObj.id=sObj.id||'Spreadsheet ID';
  sObj.found="No results found";
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(sObj.id);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sObj.haystack);
  var rg=sh.getRange(sObj.startrow,1,sh.getLastRow()-sObj.startrow+1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var v=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
    if(v[i][sObj.column-1]==sObj.needle) {
     sObj.found=v[i];
     break; 
    }
  }
  return sObj;
}

function needleInHaystackDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("aq6").setWidth(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Needle In Haystack")
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("aq6").setWidth(600);
}
```

aq5.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br /><input id="txt1" type="text" placeholder="Sheet Name" />
<br /><input id="txt2" type="text" placeholder="Search String" />
<br /><input id="txt3" type="text" placeholder="Search Column Number" />
<br /><input id="txt4" type="text" placeholder="Start Row" />
<br /><input id="txt5" type="text" placeholder="Spreadsheet ID" />
<br /><textarea id="found" rows="2" cols="50"></textarea>,
<br /><input type="button" value="Search" onClick="search();" />
<script>
  function search() {
    var s1=$('#txt1').val();
    var s2=$('#txt2').val();
    var s3=$('#txt3').val();
    var s4=$('#txt4').val();
    var s5=$('#txt5').val();
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(sObj){
      $('#found').val(sObj.found);
    })
    .findNeedleInHaystack({haystack:s1,needle:s2,column:s3,startrow:s4,id:s5});

  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested the dialog version. It worked the first time. You can test and debug the doGet().

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked just fine, returning the search string. I am retrieving the value of the result text area, but unable to break it down, for example, the string contains first name, last name, email, etc,  how can I split this information to be able to move them to separate divs in my html? I tried many ways, but in vain. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of object is the result?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. My data has First Name, Last Name, Email, Phone, Reg. No., and Serial Nb. I modified the script to have the button get the search text, paste it in a search cell inside the sheet I am using, then this will get me only one result in the "text area id="found"" as the following: John,Doe,email@email.com,966540000000,34-FG-674347,AS2020-245133. How can I separate them? I want to pull each value to a separate div in my html. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sObj.found is array. So First Name = sObj.found[0]; Last Name = sObj.found[1]; and so on.

Comment: You can use Logger.log or console.log to determine object structure.

Comment: Thank you for the help my dear. Excuse my questions, but I am not very expert with the whole thing, I tried to do that, but couldn't see where to put it. I tried in the html like and code.gs. Sorry again, your patience is appreciated.

Comment: I managed to do it using split and splice methods. I hoped there was an easier method, though. Thank you for everything. @Cooper

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to build and host this page externally (i.e. on your own website/server outside of Google's environment), or do you want to build a webpage that is coded, managed, and hosted within G Suite?

If it's the former, you'll need to work with the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) to pull data from your spreadsheet.

If it's the latter, read up on [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) for Apps Script, which allows you to build and host basic web apps in G Suite.

If you need some more examples to work from, try the search terms "host web app google apps script" in your favorite search engine.