# Connect Google Sheet into Photoshop

Tags: google-sheets, plugins, connection, photoshop

I am hardly finding a way to connect or live-import data from Google Sheet in Photoshop.

There are several way to edit or replace some text layers, or even upload the PSD file into online real time editors, or using Adobe API, but is not exactly what I am looking for or at least I am struggling with.

---

### This is the scenario:

[here my Photoshop Artboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEKTP.png)

[and here my Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJPVk.png)

what I want to do is to connect each layer from artboards' Photoshop with a defined cell/position in Google Sheet in order to get a live update when sorting or updating those cells. The cells and columns could be more than 10.000 in what I want to do.

And perhaps.. the struggling things is that I want to keep this flow in the Adobe/Photoshop application.

---

Do you have anything that I need to check or have knowledge to clearify this situation?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in principle...

Yes, it's possible to load in a .CSV into photoshop and modify layer data, such as text.

Doing it live? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143901/how-can-i-access-google-sheet-spreadsheets-only-with-javascript) has more info.

> "connect each layer from artboards' Photoshop with a defined
> cell/position"

Have you created a Photoshop document with 10,000 layers? You haven't really explained what you will be doing with the Google Sheet, so I can't help you further.

Try a prototype with smaller data sizes first - see if you can get that to work.